# Пакеты pip на Linux Mint и виртуальное окружение virtualenv

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pip, linux-mint, virtualenv

Использую Linux Mint совсем недавно. Т.к. я разрабатываю на Python, то также использую pip для установки пакетов. И ситуация такая, что на винде изначально с установкой pip идет пара системных пакетов, здесь же у меня целый список, что все мои глобальные Питоновские пакеты просто теряются.
Ко всему прочему, используя virtualenv, все мои пакеты копируются туда, чего точно не должно быть.
Подскажите, насколько важны эти глобальные пакеты, которых я вообще не знаю и что делать с виртуальным окружением?

Сами пакеты:

```html
apt-clone==0.2.1
apturl==0.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
Babel==2.9.1
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.8.3
certifi==2022.12.7
chardet==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
command-not-found==0.3
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==3.4.8
cupshelpers==1.0
dbus-python==1.2.18
defer==1.0.6
distlib==0.3.4
distro==1.7.0
eyeD3==0.8.10
filelock==3.6.0
frozenlist==1.3.3
grpcio==1.30.2
httplib2==0.20.2
idna==3.3
ifaddr==0.1.7
IMDbPY==2021.4.18
importlib-metadata==4.6.4
jeepney==0.7.1
keyring==23.5.0
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
louis==3.20.0
macaroonbakery==1.3.1
magic-filter==1.0.9
Mako==1.1.3
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
more-itertools==8.10.0
multidict==6.0.4
nemo-emblems==5.6.0
netaddr==0.8.0
netifaces==0.11.0
oauthlib==3.2.0
onboard==1.4.1
packaging==21.3
PAM==0.4.2
pexpect==4.8.0
Pillow==9.0.1
platformdirs==2.5.1
protobuf==3.12.4
psutil==5.9.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycairo==1.20.1
pycups==2.0.1
pycurl==7.44.1
pyelftools==0.27
PyGObject==3.42.1
PyICU==2.8.1
pyinotify==0.9.6
PyJWT==2.3.0
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyparted==3.11.7
pyRFC3339==1.1
python-apt==2.3.0+ubuntu2.1
python-debian===0.1.43ubuntu1
python-dotenv==0.21.0
python-gnupg==0.4.8
python-magic==0.4.24
python-xlib==0.29
pytz==2022.1
pyxdg==0.27
PyYAML==5.4.1
reportlab==3.6.8
requests-file==1.5.1
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
SecretStorage==3.3.1
setproctitle==1.2.2
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
systemd-python==234
tinycss2==1.1.1
tldextract==3.1.2
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.36.1
Unidecode==1.3.3
urllib3==1.26.5
virtualenv==20.13.0+ds
wadllib==1.3.6
webencodings==0.5.1
xdg==5
xkit==0.0.0
xlrd==1.2.0
yarl==1.8.2
youtube-dl==2021.12.17
zipp==1.0.0
```

Comment: «используя virtualenv, все мои пакеты копируются туда» — покажите как вы работаете с virtualenv (создаёте/активируете/проверяете)

Comment: @andreymal virtualenv venv --> source venv/local/bin/activate ---> pip freeze

Comment: То, что вы написали в комментарии несуществующий путь, намекает на то, что вы написали это от балды вместо того чтобы скопировать реальный текст из терминала. Покажите тогда уж скриншот что ли

Comment: (ну или вы и в самом деле пишете несуществующий путь и игнорируете появляющуюся ошибку, тогда это всё объясняет...)

Comment: @andreymal https://imgur.com/a/IwkAhzi

Comment: Исправьте pip3 на pip?

Comment: @andreymal проблема по итогу в другом. в usr/bin/ нет файла virtualenv. из-за этого все не работает, и команда без local не активирует виртуальное окружение. что интересно, я не могу удалить virtualenv и переустановить, т.к. он пишет, что такой файл не найден. замкнутый круг, приэтому в pip freeze и в файлах системы он есть

Comment: `which virtualenv` что пишет?

Comment: @andreymal вообще ничего не писало, когда я писал эту команду. сейчас получилось удалить такой командой 
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3-virtualenv
переустановил просто pip3 install virtualenv и все корректно заработало, как и должно
осталось разобраться с кучей глобальных пакетов

Comment: А ещё покажите `pip3 freeze --all | grep setuptools`

Comment: @andreymal в любом случае спасибо вам за ваше время, в желании мне помочь

Comment: @andreymal 
setuptools==65.6.3

Comment: В общем я это к тому, что в интернете говорят, что появление папки local [это баг](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3278) в новой версии setuptools 60, но в Linux Mint по умолчанию должна идти более старая версия, а значит вы наверное где-то случайно установили новую версию и таким образом всё сломали

Comment: А значит попробуйте `pip3 uninstall setuptools` и `sudo apt install python3-setuptools`

Comment: @andreymal да, видимо что-то пошло не так

Comment: А куча глобальных пакетов это нормально, потому что многие системные компоненты в Ubuntu/Mint работают на Python, и если вы попытаетесь их удалить, то скорее всего сломаете систему. Хотя пакеты вроде `Pillow` и `PyJWT` системе вроде не нужны — возможно, вы их тоже установили случайно, проверьте каталог `~/.local/lib/python*/site-packages` на наличие пакетов, установленных без виртуального окружения

Comment: @andreymal понял, звучит логично, жаль что они отображаются со всеми site-packeges

Comment: Внутри активированного virtualenv они не должны отображаться, и если они у вас до сих отображаются, то видимо что-то до сих пор сломано (но у меня уже кончились идеи что именно)

Comment: @andreymal сейчас все замечательно внутри virtualenv, спасибо!